# Is it possible with docker to run more than one app on port 80 on the same computer?

Tags: php, python, node.js, django, nginx

My thought is this.  I might not even need docker to solve the issue.  Perhaps, I can just run nginx as a reverse proxy running on port 80, the default for web applications and somehow direct them to different applications, using different programming stacks.  In other words, a Java EE server, a Node.js server, a Django app and some PHP apps.  In this scenario, nginx would serve the requests to the appropriate applications.  Is that possible?

Second scenario is having different IP addresses attached to docker images, so that each IP address can have a different application running on port 80 - the default port.

If this does not work, I guess I would need a different VPS server for each environment that I want to serve on port 80.  I have both a Linux development server which could serve low traffic sites but I also purchase VPS hosting monthly.  I'd like to avoid having to purchase separate vps server accounts for each stack, e.g. Java EE, Node.js, Python/Django with Gunicorn, and PHP apps.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice,
Bruce

Comment: Apache/Nginx can serve on the same port different applications if they have different addresses - ie. `app1.example.com`, `app2.example.com`  - it is called `virtual host`.

Comment: This is a decent guide on how to route different paths to different applications through nginx: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Comment: This information is helpful.  Thanks.  Sorry for my delay - unexpected issues arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both of your approaches suggested:

**Using NGINX as reverse proxy**

In this case the approach would be to just configure different server_name entries per docker instances, and from there do the reverse proxy to the docker instance, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name your-server-name.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

In the previous example 8082 would be the port of your docker instance.

**Mapping to different IP addresses**

If you want to, it is possible to forward the docker port to an specific IP with the -p parameter. Exactly, when launching the docker instance use this:

```
-p IP:host_port:container_port or -p IP::port
```

for setting the external interface for one particular binding

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on the way you are going to be addressing your web services. If you have the possibility to set up separate subdomains or even URL prefixes for them, NGINX - as you already guessed - has you covered. The configuration option you are looking for is proxy_pass - maybe in conjunction with setting up different subdomains for the services via the server_name directive.

So say you've got NGINX installed on localhost, a django app running on the same box on port 9000 and a Java EE server on 192.168.0.1 on port 6000, you could do sth. like this: https://gist.github.com/dreizehnelf/f92b23dea5245a3c322cdcea4e1cf362

(Sorry, couldn't post the config directly, since all the http:// stuff in it was considered links by stackoverflow - and I don't have enough reputation points to post more than two.)

Comment: Not sure if I should open a new question but to clarify, my goal is to have web servers that work on the default port so users don't have to type in a port #.  Easy to do with LAMP stack, where A is apache... and no other web server exists.  However, with a box that want to run Java EE container, Node.js, NGINX with Gunicorn and apache/php/mysql or mariadb.  Thanks